# Laravel and Firebase real time database connection

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, firebase

I want to connect laravel project with firebase.
I do this:

1. install this package form github https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync
2. configure `config/services.php`

   ```
   'firebase' => [
      'api_key' => 'AIzaSyDrioEmJqa6Ir9ocpl0UuA3No', // Only used for JS integration
      'auth_domain' => 'bum.firebaseapp.com', // Only used for JS integration
      'database_url' => 'https://8c5c.firebaseio.com',
      'secret' => '8wjs4WLjJ5hQ4lsCoUXUWiaJ3RIX',
      'storage_bucket' => 'STORAGE_BUCKET', // Only used for JS integration
   ],
   ```

I want to get data form firebase DB but when i run this command on thinker

```
App\Users::first();
```

I got this error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [2002] No connection could be made because the target machin
>       e actively refused it.
>        (SQL: select * from `users` limit 1)'

Also this is my users model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Mpociot\Firebase\SyncsWithFirebase;

class Users extends Model
{

    use SyncsWithFirebase;

    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

Do you guide me?

Comment: Double check `database_url`, `secret` and all details!

Comment: For the question i use junk data for secret info

Comment: Try: `$user = $auth->getUser('some-uid');`

Answer (score 2):

OK!
At the end I use this tutorial and fix my problem

My controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FirebaseController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/bumpin-d8c5c-firebase-adminsdk-lerig-cb68aaed.json');
        $firebase = (new Factory)
            ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)
            ->create();
            $db = $firebase->getDatabase();
            $reference = $db->getReference('users');
            $snapshot = $reference->getSnapshot();
            $value = $snapshot->getValue();
            dd($value);
            return view('welcome' , compact('value'));
    }
}
```

From your Firebase console you can get your .json file 
Follow this path:

```
 Project Preview -> Project setting -> service accounts -> firebase admin sdk
```

download private key as json file and seve it

Then move .json file to controller and use that name in the controller like my example

```
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/bumpin-d8c5c-firebase-adminsdk-lerig-cb68aaed.json');
```

I hope this help some one!

Comment: using "fromJsonFile()" gives error ->  Call to private method Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile()

Answer (score 0):

Connect [Firebase with Laravel](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/firebase-realtime-database-laravel/) using PHP SDK like this

```
public function index(){

$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/Laraveltesting-6aeda3a963f2.json');

$firebase = (new Factory)

->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)

->withDatabaseUri('https://laraveltesting-bd2b9.firebaseio.com/')

->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();

$newPost = $database

->getReference('blog/posts')

->push([

'title' => 'Post title',

'body' => 'This should probably be longer.'

]);

//$newPost->getKey(); // => -KVr5eu8gcTv7_AHb-3-

//$newPost->getUri(); // => https://my-project.firebaseio.com/blog/posts/-KVr5eu8gcTv7_AHb-3-

//$newPost->getChild('title')->set('Changed post title');

//$newPost->getValue(); // Fetches the data from the realtime database

//$newPost->remove();

echo"<pre>";

print_r($newPost->getvalue());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch all data from the database then you can use this code.

Here `$this->FIREBASE_JSON` is the unique private key and `$this->FIRE_DB_URL` is the URL of your database and these are initialized in the constructor.

```
$firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($this->FIREBASE_JSON )
        ->withDatabaseUri($this->FIREBASE_DB_URL)
        ->createDatabase();
        $data = $firebase->getReference('/')->getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which i use to perform all tasks with realtime firebase

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    private $FIREBASE_DB_URL;
    private $FIREBASE_JSON;
    private $FIREBASE;
    private $FACTORY;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->FIREBASE_DB_URL  =   env("FIREBASE_DB_URL");
        $this->FIREBASE_JSON    =   getcwd(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'assets'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'tapmap-firebase.json';
        $this->FIREBASE = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($this->FIREBASE_JSON )->withDatabaseUri($this->FIREBASE_DB_URL)->createDatabase();
        $this->FACTORY = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($this->FIREBASE_JSON);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->FIREBASE->getReference('/')->getValue();
        //render to blade file
        return view('index',['users'=>$data]);
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required',
            'lat'=>'required',
            'lng'=>'required'
        ]);

        $lastId = 1;
        if($request->lastId != null)
        {
            $lastId = $request->lastId;
        }
        // Save data to firebase without image
        if(!$request->hasFile('pic'))
        {
            $this->FIREBASE->getReference('/'.$lastId)->set([
                "title" => $request->title == '' ? '' : $request->title,
                "address" => $request->address == '' ? '' : $request->address,
                "description" => $request->description == '' ? '' : $request->description,
                "phone" => $request->phone == '' ? '' : $request->phone,
                "available_unavailable" => $request->available_unavailable == '' ? '' : $request->available_unavailable,
                "indoor_outdoor" => $request->indoor_outdoor == '' ? '' : $request->indoor_outdoor,
                "self_ask_a_member" => $request->self_ask_a_member == '' ? '' : $request->self_ask_a_member,
                "lat" => $request->lat == '' ? '' : $request->lat,
                "lng" => $request->lng == '' ? '' : $request->lng,
                "pic" => "",
            ]);
        }else{
            $storage = $this->FACTORY->createStorage();
            $image = $request->file('pic');

            $localfolder = public_path('firebase-images') .'/';
            $extension  = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $file = $lastId. '.' . $extension;
            $image_url = '';

            // Upload image to firebase storage
            if ($image->move($localfolder, $file)) {
                $uploadedfile = fopen($localfolder.$file, 'r');
                $image_url_object = $storage->getBucket()->upload($uploadedfile, [
                    'name' => 'tapImages/'.$file,
                ]);
                unlink($localfolder . $file);

                $expiresAt = new \DateTime('3100-01-01');

                $image_url = $image_url_object->signedUrl($expiresAt);
            }

            $this->FIREBASE->getReference('/'.$lastId)->set([
                "title" => $request->title,
                "address" => $request->address,
                "description" => $request->description,
                "phone" => $request->phone,
                "available_unavailable" => $request->available_unavailable,
                "indoor_outdoor" => $request->indoor_outdoor,
                "self_ask_a_member" => $request->self_ask_a_member,
                "lat" => $request->lat,
                "lng" => $request->lng,
                "pic" => $image_url,
            ]);
        }

        return back();
    }

    // Update post record
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'title'=>'required',
            'lat'=>'required',
            'lng'=>'required'
        ]);

        if($request->updateID == '' || $request->updateID == null)
        {
            return back()->with('failed','Something went wrong');
        }

        if(!$request->hasFile('update-image')){

            $this->FIREBASE->getReference('/'.$request->updateID)->set([
                "title" => $request->title,
                "address" => $request->address,
                "description" => $request->description,
                "phone" => $request->phone,
                "available_unavailable" => $request->available_unavailable,
                "indoor_outdoor" => $request->indoor_outdoor,
                "self_ask_a_member" => $request->self_ask_a_member,
                "lat" => $request->lat,
                "lng" => $request->lng,
                "pic" => $request->prev_user_pic == '' ? '' : $request->prev_user_pic,
            ]);
        }else{
            $storage = $this->FACTORY->createStorage();

            if($request->prev_user_pic != '')
            {
                $var = explode('/', $request->prev_user_pic);
                $key = array_search('tapImages', $var);
                $string = $var[$key+1];
                $file_name =  strtok($string, '?');
                $imageReference = $storage->getBucket()->object("tapImages/".$file_name);
                if($imageReference->exists())
                    $imageReference->delete();
            }

            $image = $request->file('update-image');
            $localfolder = public_path('firebase-images') .'/';
            $extension  = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $file = $request->updateID. '.' . $extension;
            $image_url = '';

            if ($image->move($localfolder, $file)) {
                $uploadedfile = fopen($localfolder.$file, 'r');
                $image_url_object = $storage->getBucket()->upload($uploadedfile, [
                    'name' => 'tapImages/'.$file,
                ]);
                unlink($localfolder . $file);

                $expiresAt = new \DateTime('3100-01-01');

                $image_url = $image_url_object->signedUrl($expiresAt);
            }

            $this->FIREBASE->getReference('/'.$request->updateID)->set([
                "title" => $request->title,
                "address" => $request->address,
                "description" => $request->description,
                "phone" => $request->phone,
                "available_unavailable" => $request->available_unavailable,
                "indoor_outdoor" => $request->indoor_outdoor,
                "self_ask_a_member" => $request->self_ask_a_member,
                "lat" => $request->lat,
                "lng" => $request->lng,
                "pic" => $image_url,
            ]);
        }
        return back();
    }

    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($this->FIREBASE_JSON);
        $storage = $factory->createStorage();

        $key = $request->id;
        if($key == '' || $key == null)
        {
            return back()->with('failed','Record id does not exists');
        }

        // Delete the image of post
        $post = $this->FIREBASE->getReference('/'.$key)->getValue();

        if($post['pic'] != '')
        {
            $var = explode('/', $post['pic']);
            $key_arr = array_search('tapImages', $var);
            $string = $var[$key_arr+1];
            $file_name =  strtok($string, '?');
            $imageReference = $storage->getBucket()->object("tapImages/".$file_name);
            if($imageReference->exists())
                $imageReference->delete();
        }


        // Delete post
        if($this->FIREBASE->getReference('/'.$key)->remove())
        {
            return back()->with('success','Post removed successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            return back()->with('failed','Something went wrong!');
        }
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        // send post details with the help of id
        $firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($this->FIREBASE_JSON )
        ->withDatabaseUri($this->FIREBASE_DB_URL)
        ->createDatabase();

        $data = $firebase->getReference('/'.$id)->getValue();

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.